# Nginx handling Domain Name Forwarding to tomcat

Tags: nginx, tomcat, proxypass

I have domain name ***xyzabc.com*** and I am hosting few sample apps at my local machine

Since My ISP **blocks port 80**, So I have to forward my domain name to Port 81; So I Defined the Forwarding (http://xx.xx.xx.xx:81) in godaddy and I configured 2 subdomains **foo.xyzabc.com** and **bar.xyzabc.com** and Used forwarding as (xx.xx.xx.xx:81) and (xx.xx.xx.xx:81) Respectively.

At my Router I defined port forwarding to map external port 81 to internal port 80, at which **nginx is Running**.

Until this point every thing is working ***xyzabc.com, foo.xyzabc.com*** with my main website content.

Now I want to map **tomcat** when somebody type *foo.xyzabc.com* to localhost:8080/ And I am confused how to configure that.

What I tried is :

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name foo.xyzabc
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 81;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect http://xx.xx.xx.xx:81/ http://localhost:8080/;
}
```

}

And

```
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_connect_timeout 150;
    proxy_send_timeout 100;
            proxy_read_timeout 100;
}
```

And **many Permutation combination** but I am not able to get the Tomcat webpage when typing foo.xyzabc.com/

I will really appreciate any help in this.

Comment: I Can't use http:// because I don't have 10 Reputation so you might see the domain without http.

Answer (score 0):

Your `server_name` should contain exact match for your host name, e.g. `foo.xyzabc.com` instead of `foo.xyzabc`. Also the first `location /` example is missing `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer but I tried that too.

Comment: @Tiwari you need to specify what is your current configuration state exactly and what errors you are getting.